# This site can't be reached (refussed to connect) laravel project on digitalocean

Tags: laravel, apache, digital-ocean, lamp

I install LAMP on my droplet in digital ocean, it did works good but now just tell "this site can't be reached, refused to connection" my IP is 157.230.139.112

My project worked well, however, from one day to the next, that simply appeared. I did not have anything important and decided to delete it and create a new droplet, however the same thing happens, I can make migrations and connect with the bd but only rejects the connection.

[image]

I did install composer, all the packages, configure my db and my etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf and point to the public folder.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is your `.env` file setup correctly?

Comment: Do you have a firewall? What do your Apache logs say? What does your Apache config look like? The question is too broad for us to do anything but guess.  Do some investigation and give us more details. Does HTML work? Is Apache even running? If it is a new site are you sure your DNS has propagated?

Comment: check your apache log file against the time you got this error. If your os is ubuntu or debian it is located somewhere in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 2):

Your apache server block might not be pointing to your laravel location correctly.
So, you might try configuring Apahce2 site configuration file for Laravel. 
Run the command below to create a new configuration file called laravel.conf

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf
```

Copy paste the content below into the file and save it. Remember to replace 'Mywebsite' with your own domain name and directory root location.Remember to point to laravel public folder for security.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>   
   ServerAdmin admin@MyWebsite.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyWebsite/public
      ServerName example.com

      <Directory /var/www/html/MyWebsite/public>
         Options +FollowSymlinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Save the file and exit.

Enable the Laravel and Rewrite Module
Enable the VirtualHost by running ..

```
 sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Alternatively, compare your localhost apache serverblock configuration with that on the server, ie. if you are running apache locally